# Restore from SQL Server 2014 Enterprise to BI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore, partitioning

Is it possible to restore a SQL Server 2014 Enterprise database with table partitioning (Production) to a SQL Server 2014 BI Version (Test/Development) ?

Of course I don't expect to use the table partitioning Feature on BI version, but I do expect a runnable version ...

Answer (score 1):

You can restore it if you're not using any Enterprise Edition features.

In this case, you are using table partitioning so that restore path is not supported.

You can run:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;
```

...to check for other features that can block your cross-edition restore.

Consider using Developer Edition as your test/development platform. It is very cheap and has all of the features of Enterprise Edition.